# Cannot download Bamboo remote agent jar

Tags: bamboo

I'm trying to download the Bamboo Remote Agent Jar to my agent server but when I click the download link I get this error page:

```
Internal server error
Go to...
Site homepage
A system error has occurred - our apologies!
Please create a problem report on our support system at https://support.atlassian.com with the following information:

a description of your problem and what you were doing at the time it occurred
cut & paste the error and system information found below
attach the atlassian-bamboo.log log file found in your application home.
We will respond as promptly as possible.
Thank you!
Version: 7.1.3
Build: 70121
Build Date: 15 Oct 2020

Request information:
Request URL: http://server_ip/500.action
Scheme: http
Server: server_ip
Port: 80
URI: /500.action
Context path:
Servlet path: /500.action
Path info:
Query string:
Stack Trace:

io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:156)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:116)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference.get(ResettableLazyReference.java:95)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.AgentInstallerServlet.doGet(AgentInstallerServlet.java:117)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:24)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.UniversalAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(UniversalAnalyticsFilter.java:75)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:33)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFixupFilter.java:32)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:80)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:51)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.filter.NewRelicTransactionNamingFilter.doFilter(NewRelicTransactionNamingFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.ww2.StrutsPrepareFilter.handleRequest(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:49)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.ww2.StrutsPrepareFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareFilter.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.filter.BambooProfilingFilter.doFilter(BambooProfilingFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.filter.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.filter.LicenseFilter.doFilter(LicenseFilter.java:74)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.johnson.filters.AbstractJohnsonFilter.doFilter(AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:242)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:148)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BambooLoginFilter.doFilter(BambooLoginFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:67)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:94)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.filter.RequestCacheThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheThreadLocalFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.filter.ClickjackingAndMimeTypeSniffingPreventionFilter.doFilter(ClickjackingAndMimeTypeSniffingPreventionFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.filter.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.HeaderSanitisingFilter.doFilter(HeaderSanitisingFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.DefaultAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(DefaultAnalyticsFilter.java:26)
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:33)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:57)
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:62)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:55)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(StuckThreadDetectionValve.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1626)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:156)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:116)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference.get(ResettableLazyReference.java:95)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.AgentClassServerImpl.getJarsOnSystemClasspath(AgentClassServerImpl.java:132)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.AgentClassServerImpl.getSystemClasspath(AgentClassServerImpl.java:123)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.AgentClassServerImpl.lambda$classPathFileSupplier$1(AgentClassServerImpl.java:199)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.BambooFileUtils$1.get(BambooFileUtils.java:443)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.BambooFileUtils$1.get(BambooFileUtils.java:434)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.io.FileInputSupplier.openStream(FileInputSupplier.java:28)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.AgentInstallerServlet$1.create(AgentInstallerServlet.java:92)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.AgentInstallerServlet$1.create(AgentInstallerServlet.java:37)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference$InternalReference.create(ResettableLazyReference.java:185)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$Sync.run(LazyReference.java:332)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:150)
    ... 163 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.BambooObjectUtils.asRuntimeException(BambooObjectUtils.java:119)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.ClasspathDiscovererImpl.createJarFromResource(ClasspathDiscovererImpl.java:169)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.ClasspathDiscovererImpl.discoverClasspath(ClasspathDiscovererImpl.java:91)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.AgentClassServerImpl$1.create(AgentClassServerImpl.java:83)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.AgentClassServerImpl$1.create(AgentClassServerImpl.java:78)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.ResettableLazyReference$InternalReference.create(ResettableLazyReference.java:185)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$Sync.run(LazyReference.java:332)
    at io.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:150)
    ... 176 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create file: c:\Program Files\Bamboo\temp\jarFromResource4243020160613851350.jar
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.SecureTemporaryFiles.createSecureTempFile(SecureTemporaryFiles.java:255)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.SecureTemporaryFiles.createPath(SecureTemporaryFiles.java:211)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.SecureTemporaryFiles.create(SecureTemporaryFiles.java:206)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.agent.classserver.ClasspathDiscovererImpl.createJarFromResource(ClasspathDiscovererImpl.java:153)
    ... 182 more
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: c:\Program Files\Bamboo\temp\jarFromResource4243020160613851350.jar
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
    at com.atlassian.bamboo.util.SecureTemporaryFiles.createSecureTempFile(SecureTemporaryFiles.java:250)
    ... 185 more
```

How can I get this downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

The exception Could not create file: c:\Program Files\Bamboo\temp\jarFromResource4243020160613851350.jar denotes that the user as which you are running Bamboo doesn't have permission to write to the temp directory.

We usually see these problems when you start Bamboo with different user (therefore different permissions). If you are starting Bamboo as a service, please switch the service to run as the local user as detailed below:

[Running Bamboo as a Windows service as the local user](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/running-bamboo-as-a-windows-service-as-the-local-user-416580754.html)

Ensure that the local user has read/write access to C:\Program Files\Bamboo\temp\ directory.

You may also start Bamboo via bin/start-bamboo.bat to overcome this issue.